# ¿Como crear rama excluyendo carpeta?

Tags: git, gitlab

En el repositorio principal tengo dos carpetas
HTML
PROYECTOWEB

Y necesito crear una rama proy-dev **pero que en esa rama no exista la carpeta HTML**.

Todo lo anterior en un mismo repositorio.

Comment: En la carpeta del repositorio git debes crear si no lo tienes un archivo llamado ".giitingore" y en el debes escribir los nombres de archivos, extensiones, rutas que desees que git ignore. Si tienes los archivos ya pusheados en tu repositorio de git deberas eliminarlos para que el git no los detecte y tome cambios.
Este post esta relacionado:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308610/how-to-ignore-certain-files-in-git/44132149

Answer (score 0):

lo que debes hacer es crear el archivo `.gitignore` y añadir la carpeta dentro del archivo para que git sepa que se debe ignorar ese directorio o archivo.

**1º paso**

- Crear el archivo `.gitignore` en la carpeta raíz de tu proyecto.

**2º paso**

- Entrar en el archivo `.gitignore`.

Añadir en el archivo la carpeta HTML.

```
/HTML
```